# Using microphone as input on iBooks Widget or .js game on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, html, io, ibooks

I'm converting a Processing Game (that I've made last year) to a widget to embed on iBooks Author. 
I do know that we can embed html or javascript on a widget to publish on iBook, but I couldn't find some integrations to use microphone from an iPad in real time using javascript. 
Is this possible?

The game is basicly whisper on the microphone to pass a level, like mario bros running.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't access the microphone in an HTML widget in iBooks Author. The only workarounds I've found are to create a native iOS app that can access it.